# Spring 5 State Based Bean Injection - possible?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to find some 'controller' (not @Controller) within Spring 5.0 that is responsible to resolve what instance of an implementation to inject within Spring. I want to provide my own implementation of that controller (or to extend it), so that I can add my own logic for state-based bean resolution.

For example, given some interface Foo, with implementation FooImpl1 and FooImpl2, and some state Baz.

Then, when Baz = 1, I want to step into my own logic to decide to provide FooImpl1 instead of FooImpl2 for the required inject of Foo implementation.

Spring does this today, the logic seems to be:

- Given the need to inject class X, find its implementations
- If only one of X is found, use that
- If more than one X is found, use Primary
- If more than one X is found and no Primary, find Qualifier
- If more than one X if found and no Primary and no Qualifier, attempt to match X with property or parameter X by name (ie: don't inject Y if the parameter or property is x and not y).

What I want to do is at some point in the logic above, to invoke my own disambiguation/resolution of the required implementation to be injected, based on my own logic and state.

So, before I go and dig into Spring to locate where that logic is implemented, I am hoping to find that it is implemented in some controller/service that I can extend, best still if this is backed by some configuration...

Comment: If you use an `@Bean` method to provide the bean, the method can do whatever it wants to decide which class to instantiate. But of course, the state used to decide it must be known at that time. What is this state you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own [@Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-configuration-annotation) that returns a Spring [@Bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-bean-annotation):

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    private final Baz baz;

    @Autowired
    Config(Baz baz) {
        this.baz = baz
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo getFoo() {
        switch (baz) {
            case 1:
                return new FooImpl1();
            default:
                return new FooImpl2();
        }    
    }
}
```

Please also read the paragraph about [Full @Configuration vs “lite” @Bean mode?](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts). The last paragraph states that:

> In common scenarios, @Bean methods are to be declared within @Configuration classes, ensuring that “full” mode is always used and that cross-method references therefore get redirected to the container’s lifecycle management. This prevents the same @Bean method from accidentally being invoked through a regular Java call, which helps to reduce subtle bugs that can be hard to track down when operating in “lite” mode.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the simplest solution, though for my needs I will probably go with a BeanFactory implemenation. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

It seems what I am looking for are the interfaces BeanFactory and most likely ConfigurableBeanFactory. There are still some things to work through off-course, but this definitely is the right direction.

For those immediately curious as to what I am talking about ... see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableBeanFactory.html